# I don’t understand warrants. Why can I sell calls for profit without reaching strike?

Tags: stocks, warrants

I understand the basic concept which is explained everywhere. But apparently this is not what happens.

It is written everywhere, that the difference between strike price and actual stock price is my profit. So if I do a call, The stock price has to be above the strike price to take profits, right? Otherwise I would just get nothing.

Despite that, I can just buy warrants and sell them whenever I want. Now, why is this? In my Online Broker I can trade them normally like stocks. Buy them, wait till the price rises, sell. I buy them and sell them. And I can make profit without ever reaching the strike price.

I don’t understand the system. Please explain that :/

Comment: You can trade options too, whether they're in the money or not. Not entirely sure what you're asking about. Warrant is basically an option issued by the company itself (with some additional differences irrelevant to this question).

Comment: You had to pay to purchase the call option for money because it had potential value.  Before expiry it still has potential value, probably changed from what it used to be but still positive.  So you can sell it now rather than waiting to see what happens.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> The stock price has to be above the strike price to take profits, right?

To be picky, the stock has to be above the strike *to get a payout*. To make a profit, the payout you get has to be more then the *premium* you pay for the stock. But I think you meant a payout, not necessarily a profit.  If the stock is below the strike *at expiry*, the option will expire worthless any your net loss is the premium you paid.

You can still buy and sell warrants (analytically similar to "call options") even if the stock is below the strike *before expiry*. The reason is that you're betting that the stock price will rise and eventually be *above* the strike. If the stock price goes up, the chance is greater that it will be above the strike at expiry, and the warrant is more valuable (i.e. you can sell it for a profit before expiry).

In other words, you *might* get a payout, and you might not. So you're paying for the *probability* of a payout.  If that probability goers up, the value of the warrant goes up.

As you get closer to the expiry date, the amount that the stock can realistically move decreases, so the change in the option value just based on the movement of the stock decreases. If the stock is far below the strike, the odds will be very small that it pays out, and the value will not change much. If the stock is near the strike, there's roughly a 50/50 chance that it will move above the strike, and the option will have some value. If it's already above the strike, the value will be close to the difference between the stock and the strike.

That's a pretty simplistic view, and there's a lot of nuance, but that's the basic idea why options that are currently "out of the money" can still be traded and make a proft before expiry.

Comment: Warrants are a very specific type of call options. They're issued by the company, and when exercised new shares are issued instead of existing shares exchanging hands and the company gets the money instead of another investor.

Comment: True, but analytically they are basically the same as call options (assuming the dilutive effects are negligible), so I approached it from that direction. I'll rephrase though.

Comment: Aaaaah. So, if I just buy and sell the warrants for profit, the price of the underlying stock can be lower than the strike price? I don’t have to pay any penalty for that? It is just like normal trading? I had the fear that eventually the emittent would charge me the strike price for my trades days later, because I just traded them like normal stocks^^

Comment: exactly - essentially, someone _else_ is paying more for that same probability than you did. To be clear, there's no guarantee that you _can_ sell for profit, but mechanically that's how it would work.

Comment: You only pay the strike price if you hold the option until expiry (and only if it's less than the current price). It's much more common for options to be sold just prior to expiry unless you actually _want_ the stick.

Comment: That’s a relief. So if I just buy and sell them like normal stocks before expiry, I only pay what the Online Broker shows me in the transaction right? Nice. Then I understood the whole thing. It was just very misleading, that apparently no one executes the warrant. Everything that is explained online is for the execution, but most people just seem to trade them normally. that is confusing at first.

Comment: Well I wouldn't say "no one executes the warrant". But yes, once you sell the warrant you are no longer obligated to do anything related to it.